# To retrieve primary key from data extension into a variable dynamically

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I tried the below code but I am not getting any output.

My DE name is `MasterContactData`

Primary key is `AcademyID` which is to be retrieved into a variable dynamically

My script goes as below:

```
%%[
var @a,@b
set @a=AttributeValue('AcademyID')
set @b=Lookup('MasterContactData','Name','AcademyID',@a)
]%%
%%=v(@b)=%%
```

Even if there is a single record in the DE it is not displaying the value.what enhancement can be done in order to get each value in the variable by incrementing once each time.

Comment: What data extension are you using to send from?  MasterContactData?  If that's true, you don't have to use a lookup function but rather just use the ampscript identifier inline with your html email.  ie.  %%=(name)=%%

Answer (score 0):

You use the [**LookupRows()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookuprows.htm) function and iterate through all rows by `AcademyID` and output the values for `Name`:

```
%%[

var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @numRowsToReturn, @lookupValue, @i

set @lookupValue = AttributeValue("AcademyID") 
set @numRowsToReturn = 0 /* 0 means all, max 2000 */
set @rows = LookupRows("MasterContactData","AcademyID", @lookupValue)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

    var @Name
    set @row = row(@rows,@i) /* get row based on counter */
    set @Name = field(@row,"Name")

    ]%%

    <br>Row %%=v(@i)=%%, Name: is %%=v(@Name)=%%

    %%[ 

  next @i ]%%

%%[ else ]%%

No rows found

%%[ endif ]%%
```

Your sending audience would need to have an `AcademyID` Data Extension column or Profile Attribute.